# Reset a variable every day with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

We are working on a program in Spring Boot that allows a user to enter a date and the program must return a reference of the form `DD/MM/YY/VAR` where `VAR` is a variable that must be incremented by one (for each entry), and the next day must start again on 1.

For example:

1. For today: for the first entry the reference must be `13/11/20/1` and
   for the second entry the reference must be `13/11/20/2`, etc.
2. For tomorrow: for the first entry, the reference must be `14/11/20/1`
   and for the second entry the reference must be `14/11/20/2` etc.

How do I do this in Java with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a variable called currentDate, every time you access the reference you will check the currentDate and actual date. If actual date is not equal to currentDate , you can reset the var and currentDate.

At application startup, set

```
LocalDateTime currentDate = LocalDateTime.now();
int var = 1;
```

When you insert reference entry

```
LocalDateTime actualDate = LocalDateTime.now();
if(actualDate.getDayOfMonth() != currentDate.getDayOfMonth()){
    currentDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    var = 1;
}
```

Comment: simple and elegant

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by Java Scheduler. Using Java Scheduler, `VAR` can be re-initialized to 1 on the next day. You can visit the below site to learn how to schedule a job in Java:
https://dzone.com/articles/schedulers-in-java-and-spring